# Gordita font symbols appear pixelated and shifted in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, fonts

I'm trying to replace font of my application on Windows to Gordita font, the problem is that this font often appears pixelated and space between characters is sometimes inconsistent, some elements of letters even shifted (take a look at screenshots). I tried to use different files and formats (otf and ttf) for this font but the problem is still here. Also I tried to open font file in editor such as FontForge but everything looks OK there. The question is - maybe there are some options that I've missed when loading this font? Does anybody have used custom fonts and came across similar issue?

I use this code to load my fonts from resources:

```
const int id{ QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Gordita-Regular.otf") };
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Gordita-Bold.otf");
QString family{ QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0) };
QFont font{ family };
font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias);
QApplication::setFont(font);
```

And similar to this code in stylesheets to set font for widgets:

```
font-family: Gordita;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 18px;
```

Examples of bad symbols:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: use points instead of pixels

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ yep, thank you, that has noticeably improved overall look of the font, it still appears somewhat pixelated and shifted though but it's not so apparent now, is there anything else I can do to fix the font?